# Merge columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two columns of a data frame into one long column using R. I have a reproducible data below:

```
data<-data.frame(x=c(4,5,6,7,7,7),y=c(3,4,5,6,7,7))
data
  x y
1 4 3
2 5 4
3 6 5
4 7 6
5 7 7
6 7 7
```

I want to change the above data frame into the following;

```
  new
1  4
2  5
3  6
4  7
5  7
6  7
7  3
8  4
9  5
10 6
11 7
12 7
```

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `unlist`

```
data.frame(new = unlist(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr::bind_rows(new$x, new$y)` works as well

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the dataframe to matrix and then to vector :

```
data.frame(new = c(as.matrix(data)))

#   new
#1    4
#2    5
#3    6
#4    7
#5    7
#6    7
#7    3
#8    4
#9    5
#10   6
#11   7
#12   7
```

Or get the data in long format :

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(data, cols = everything())
```

and keep only the `value` column.